# directive does not get executed on $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a bit struggling to get my head around `.directive`, what I'm trying to do is to force/ or a way so that the directive is called if value changes. Right now the value only gets changed when I refresh the browser. However, I want the value to dynamically gets replaced if it gets changed by some other service.

here is the controller

```
$scope.status = 'warning';
```

here is the html

```
<tr>
   <th>status</th>
   <td><icon-selector filterby="status"></icon-selector></td>
</tr>
```

here is the directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('iconSelector', function ($compile, $timeout) {

    var linkingFunction = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('filterby', function () {
            if (scope.filterby === 'OK') {
                element.replaceWith('<p>Running OK</p>');
            } else {
                element.replaceWith('<p>Not running</p>');
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            filterby: '=filterby'
        },
        link: linkingFunction
    };
});
```

Now if I set `$scope.status = 'danger';` with `$watch` in place, I would expect the function in `directive to be executed again but it does not get executed, it only get executed when page is reloaded.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your watch trigger is replacing the directive element.

So basically, after the first trigger, the element you ask to replace is still the directive element, but eh, it's not in the document anymore, because you already replaced it the first time. funny, isnt ?

Why not only replacing the text (or the inner html is you really need to) in the directive instead of replacing the whole element ( a directive element should NEVER be replaced on the fly, only angular inner compilation has the 'right' to do so )

EDIT : the example :

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('iconSelector', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace : true,
            template : '<span>{{message}}</span>',
            scope: {
                filterby: '='
            },
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watch('filterby', function (filterby) {
                    if (filterby === 'OK') {
                        $scope.message = 'Running OK';
                    } else {
                        $scope.message = 'Not running';
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Hmm..weird, so how is that done, can you show me an example here please.

Comment: here you go ( note the "replace" : true & template properties )

Comment: So does my html remains the same shown in the question block gets changed?

Comment: can I do this `$scope.message = '<img class="icon" src="sample.png">';`? Instead of text, I want to return like an icon, is that possible?

Comment: nope, but you can instead do this : template : '<img class="icon" src="{{iconPath}}">' and  $scope.iconPath = "sample.png" in the js;